# How to remove the space after \perp?

Tags: spacing, symbols

This is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent
$\perp(1)$. \\
$\alpha(1)$.
\end{document}
```

It renders as such:

[image]

As you see, the space after `\alpha` is much smaller than the space after the `\perp` command. Why and how to make `\perp` render as all other symbols, without this extra space?

Comment: I haven't checked, but it looks like `\perp` is defined as a relation.  A quick hack to make it behave like an ordinary (unspaced) character is to wrap it in braces: `{\perp}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The extra space you're seeing appears because `\perp` is a relation, so it has the spacing from `\mathrel`. You can use `\bot`, which produces the same symbol but is a `\mathord`, so has no extra spacing.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\perp(1)$.

$\bot(1)$.

$\alpha(1)$.
\end{document}
```